# Windows 7: Generate image with programs installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image

I'm **quite tired** of formatting my *family/friends* laptops and PC's and I'm looking a tool that allows me to **generate a Windows 7 image** with some **software already installed** on it

I know there is a tool like that on **Windows**, but there is a problem if you try to use the same image in different computers, issues about drivers and other stuff.

I also know another tool called **Ghost** that I've used in my own computer but there is the same issues about generating a "*standard*" image to use in different computers.

- Which is the best way to generate an image with some basic software installed on it (Adobe, VLC, Java, Chrome, Winrar, Acrobat reader...) ?

Comment: Windows can do this out of the box.  Use ImageX and generate a .WIM file

Answer (score 1):

Acronis is an imaging tool that has a feature called Universal Restore... it resets the HAL (hardware/driver configuration) so that you can port images between machines.
It isn't perfect and can't handle wildly different hardware (such as different chipset makers), but I've used it extensively in IT shops to clone images between machines that were at least reasonably similar.

Comment: If you run sysprep before you make the image, it will then install on any hardware without issue, you will then have to install any drivers you need on the new hardware, Sysprep is built into W7, you can find it in C:\Windows\System32\sysprep